# Unparseable date when running hibernate against hsqldb

Tags: java, hibernate, date, hsqldb

I have exported the sql from oracle db, which has this line:

```
to_timestamp('23-APR-09 06.11.52.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
```

I have class called `Test` which has an instance called `date` of type `TimeStamp`. Like:

```
@Entity class Test
{
   TimeStamp date
}
```

when I try to run these codes:

```
session.createSQLQuery("insert into Test (date) values(to_timestamp('23-APR-09 06.11.52.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'))").executeUpdate()
```

I get an exception like:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:365)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: data exception: invalid datetime format: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "23-APR-09 06.11.52.000000000 PM"
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:210)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "23-APR-09 06.11.52.000000000 PM"
    ... 7 more
```

where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
insert into Test (date) values(to_timestamp('23-APR-09 06.11.52.000000000 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM'))
```

According to HSQL documentation at:  http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_datetime_format  when using the **R** notation to represent a year, it must be four R's ( RRRR ) . . . but . . . your definition is a two digit year, so, use **YY** instead.